# How to Auto Compile For the Command Line Using Javac From Within a Class?

Tags: java, cmd, javac

Is there code for a class to automatically call javac when it is executed via the command line? Such as calling java Text, and within Text.java a section of code is run that automatically calls javac Text.java to re-compile the byte code.

I want to make it easier to edit a file through eclipse, and then run it via the command line without having to manually type javac over and over to rec-compile the classes byte code to reflect new changes.

Comment: You know eclipse compiles java files for you?

Comment: I know, but I specifically want to compile using the cmd, not eclipse.

Comment: I don't get it. You say _I specifically want to compile using the cmd, not eclipse_. How is this cmd different from `javac` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java 11 and later can "execute" a Java source file directly so it does not have to be compiled with javac first (by transparently invoking the compiler in the process)

From JEP 330 (https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330)

> For example, if a file called Factorial.java contains a class called
>   Factorial to calculate the factorials of its arguments, then the
>   command
>
> ```
> java Factorial.java 3 4 5
> ```
>
> is informally equivalent to
>
> ```
> javac -d <memory> Factorial.java 
> java -cp <memory> Factorial 3 4 5
> ```

If you use this, please report back how it worked for you.